# Memory efficient encoding logic for group categories

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model, encoding, efficiency, categorical-encoding

I have a huge dataset with categorical data. It is comprised of alerts having multiple properties. Each alert belongs to a group, and some even belong to multiple groups. It looks somewhat like this:

```
     GroupID           System        State       TimeStamp        etc...
0    [1, 2, 3, 4]         A           REC           ...
1    [1, 2, 3, 4]         A           SNT           ...
2    [2, 4]               B           REC 
3    [2, 4]               B           PND
4    [2, 4]               B           COM
5    [2, 4]               B           SNT
6    [2]                  C           RCV
7    [2]                  C           ACC
...
```

There are more than 100000 different group IDs in over 3 mil alerts.

1. Creating a column with a single Group ID value (not a list) means some alerts will appear more than once, which is not good given the already huge dataset.
2. Creating a separate column for each group (binary encoding) would expand my data too much horizontally.

What is a memory efficient way of encoding Groups?

Comment: How many unique combinations of multiple groups, and do you need to keep the detail of every group id in a combination? If not you could consider replacing every combination with a single new id.

Comment: @Erwan The number of combinations would be even greater than the number of group IDs...

Answer (score 1):

There is several techniques that could work for you:

- [Target Encoder](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/targetencoder.html): Works well when there is a high cardinality of a categorical feature.
- [Ordinal/Label Encoding](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/ordinal.html): Tradition label encoding
- [Weight Of Evidence](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/woe.html):  tells the predictive power of an independent variable in relation to the dependent variable